# How to use Saved Card in Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2, ecommerce

I was able to save cards by using `savePaymentSource` parameter in my payment form submitting at `commerce/payments/pay`. But how do I use these saved cards for making payments? I am using Stripe payment method and rendering the form through `{{ cart.gateway.getPaymentFormHtml({})|raw }}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit a `paymentSourceId` to the payments/pay controller action.

```
<select id="paymentSourceId" name="paymentSourceId">
    {% for storedCard in storedCards %}
        <option value="{{ storedCard.id }}" {% if storedCard.id == cart.paymentSourceId %}selected{% endif %}>{{ storedCard.description }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question. It shows how to output a list of saved cards but not how to actually submit and use them as a payment source. How does one submit this without Stripe trying to validate any card input fields on the same form (which would be a common scenario)?

Comment: The key element is, of course, the first line of the answer. The payment source submits to a different controller to the actual payment.
In short, separate forms are needed to switch payment methods and making an actual payment.